# Statement error in main of defined structure from header in C

Tags: c, struct, header-files

I'm second year (learning phase T_T). We learn structures now and I decided to try headers. But they seem to do not want to work, too lazy or something :D

The problem is that the 'Vector' structure which is defined in header file *init.h* which is ***included*** in the *main.c* for futher use. Was thinking everything is cool but error occured! Damn, it highlightes `Vector* vStart;` line (THE ERROR LINE).  Well after some reasearch of that error I have found that it's very general error which occur in either the structure or header related cases.

> Error code: 
>   a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a
>   statement

Example:

*init.h*

```
#ifndef INIT_H
#define INIT_H
#define vecLength 4

typedef struct Vector {
double * vector;
int N;
} Vector;

typedef struct Matrix {
double ** matrix;
int nRow;
int nCol;
} Matrix;

int matrixInit(Matrix* nMatrix);
int vectorInit(Vector* nVector);

#endif // INIT_H
```

*main.c*

```
    #include "init.h"

  main(){ 
    ...
    ...
    switch(_char)
    {
    case Start:
        Vector* vStart;
        if(vectorInit(vStart)){
            getStartPoint(vStart);
            vectorPrint(vStart);
        }

        else{
            hFe("Vector vStart is not created!");
            return 1;
        }

        getch();
        break;

    case Translation:
        hFe(NULL);
        return 1;

    case Exit:
        return 0;

    default:
        system("cls");
        goto AGAIN;
    }
  }
```

Comment: *Where* is the error, on which line? Where is the label `AGAIN`?

Comment: Also, there are situations when using labels and `goto` is fine. Using it instead of a loop (which I'm guessing you're doing) is not.

Comment: What is the return type of your `main()`? which compiler are you using. And as @JoachimPileborg said, this is precisely why some people hate `goto` so much.

Comment: Have excluded both label and goto, still not working

Comment: Was thinking everything is cool but error occured! Damn, it highlightes Vector* vStart;

Comment: @RandomNoob Since you are learning, try learning tools that don't force you to use ugly and OS specific things like `system("cls")` or `getch()`.

Comment: @iharob what's wrong with those two? It's just a console application xD

Comment: They are not standard. For example `system("cls")` is only ok on Windows OS. And `getch()` is too AFAIK. If you have to use `getch()` it's because the console window is closed when your program exits. You can learn how to work on a linux system where you have control of everything.

Comment: @RandomNoob They are telling you to avoid using goto the way you do because it is bad programming practice - it is not related to the error.

Comment: say OP, no profanity is necessary and we all would prefer if you did not use any

Comment: here is a proper way to keep the console window open:   `while( int ch = getchar() && EOF != ch && '\n' != ch );` then `getchar();`   Which cleans the input stream, then waits for the user to press a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a somewhat modern C compiler, the error is not at all related to scope as the present answers suggest.

Like the compiler says: "error: a label can only be part of a statement and a declaration is not a statement". The error merely comes from incorrect label syntax. `case` follows the syntax rules of labels, the syntax must be like this (6.8.1):

```
labeled-statement:
  identifier : statement
  case constant-expression : statement
  default : statement
```

Meaning a label must be followed by a statement, not a declaration or something else that isn't regarded as a statement in C. So you get the same compiler error as you would get if attempting something like `goto label; label: int x;`

One way to dodge the compiler error is simply to add an empty statement:

```
case Start:
  ;
  Vector* vStart;
```

That being said, you might still want a local scope for each case by adding braces: doing so is good practice.

Looking at the greater picture however, it doesn't seem like it even makes sense to declare `vStart` in a local scope anyhow. You should declare it at the beginning of main and initialize it to a safe value, for example NULL.

Comment: @RandomNoob,  Again, NO PROFANITY.  and what is necessary in assembly language, like jump and branch statements is not (ever) desirable in the C language.  Rather, use the looping statements like `while()` and `for()` and `do...while();`   In general, `goto` statements result in `spaghetti` code, make the code difficult to understand, and (as your are finding out) can be a real nightmare to debug

Answer (score 1):

Change your `switch` `case` to

```
   case Start:
   {
       Vector* vStart;
       if(vectorInit(vStart))
       {
          getStartPoint(vStart);
          vectorPrint(vStart);
       }
       else
       {
           hFe("Vector vStart is not created!");
           return 1;
       }

       getch();
    }
    break;
```

In this way, with brackets, you create a scope inside the case where you can declare variables.
BTW you should declare it at the top of your function to make a readable code.

Comment: However, the error isn't related to scope but to label syntax.

Answer (score -1):

A label must be on a separate line, in general starting in the first column of the line, and have nothing else on the line.  I.E.

```
mylabel:
```